# Multiple IPSec Tunnels on Cisco router's interface

Tags: cisco, vpn, ipsec

I an trying to configure 2 IPSEC VPSN Tunnels on the Cisco 1941 WAN Port. The tunnel with the higher crypto map sequence pre-empts the lower sequence number so only one tunnel is active at a time. I need both to be active simultaneously. Below is main configs. Parts omitted for brevity.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

```
R2(config)# crypto isakmp policy 1
R2(config-isakmp)# encr des
R2(config-isakmp)# hash md5
R2(config-isakmp)# authentication pre-share
R2(config-isakmp)# group 1
R2(config-isakmp)# lifetime 29800
```

ex

```
R2(config)# crypto isakmp key 1234567890 address 192.235.X.X
R2(config)# crypto isakmp key 1234567 address 65.183.10.90

R2(config)# ip access-list extended VPNTRAFFIC-BDOS
R2(config-ext-nacl)# permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.254.0 0.0.0.255

R2(config)# ip access-list extended VPNTRAFFIC-JCA
R2(config-ext-nacl)# permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 188.155.100.0 0 0.0.0.255



R2(config)# crypto ipsec transform-set TS-BDOS esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
R2(config)#crypto ipsec transform-set TS-JCA esp-des esp-md5-hmac


R2(config)# crypto map CMAP-ROTO 10 ipsec-isakmp
R2(config)#set pfs group 1
R2(config-crypto-map)# set peer 192.235.X.X
R2(config-crypto-map)# set transform-set TS-BDOS
R2(config-crypto-map)# match address VPNTRAFFIC-BDOS
R2(config)# crypto map CMAP-ROTO 100  ipsec-isakmp
R2(config-crypto-map)# set pfs group 1
R2(config-crypto-map)# set peer 65.183.X>X
R2(config-crypto-map)# set transform-set TS-JCA
R2(config-crypto-map)# match address VPNTRAFIC-JCA
```

Comment: Do you have a specific route for 192.168.254.0/24 and 188.155.100.0/24, or do you use the default route? Does one tunnel get torn down when the other tunnel comes up?